# How do I create a 32-bit WINE prefix?

Tags: 64-bit, wine, 32-bit

How do I create a 32-bit Wine prefix on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

To create a 32-bit WINE prefix on a 64-bit Ubuntu system, you need to open a terminal and run the following command:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
```

- Where `WINEPREFIX` is the directory for the prefix
- **This directory must not already exist or you will [get an error!](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29661)** Please do not manually create it in Nautilus or with *mkdir*./

Comment: thx! I have been fighting with this for a week :(, the message could be more specific..

Comment: You can use double quotes everywhere, no need for single quotes :)

Comment: When I run this command, Wine asks for an absolute path (so `/home/username/prefix32` rather than `~/prefix32`

Comment: @shea edited the OP accordingly

Comment: Also, you can omit the quotes altogether.

Comment: fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ee8a0, overlapped 0x10ee8ac): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/test/.wine' has been updated.

Comment: Will this work: "sudo apt-get install wine32" ?

Comment: I tried to perform this, to get a 32 bit Wine prefix, with sudo -i and my password, but... The Ubuntu system tells me: "wine: '/home/jjpg' is not owned by you, refusing to create a configuration directory there"  How could it be if I'm the only one SuperUser here?

Answer (score 58):

This Is how I did it. The above answer - for me - did not work.

First I deleted the Wine folder with this command:

```
rm -r ~/.wine
```

If it tells you that directory is not empty just add the `-f` (force) flag. *Note that this will remove any windows applications installed in this prefix!*

Your command should look something like this:

```
rm -r -f ~/.wine
```

And then create a 32 bit prefix with this command:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine wine wineboot
```

Comment: First, you shouldn't have to write sudo in the front. Also, this will delete the entire virtual windows drive.

Comment: That's not correct answer, because u're deleting 64bit version. You just have to create another PREFIX in order to have them both.

Comment: Where you wrote "write sudo in front", the correct solution is to add `-f`, as in `rm -rf ~/.wine`. Adding sudo won't do anything. Also, `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine` is redundant, since that's the default location.

Comment: Why not just create a `.wine32` directory instead?

Comment: @Levan how on earth did it not work for you? Your command deletes the entire existing wine directory, when all you needed to do was create a separate wine32 prefix - no need to delete an existing one.

Comment: It was the only solutions that worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

Just creating a `wine32` prefix/directory (without `wine64` prefix/directory) will not work. As was suggested above (but not fully written out) - and if you want to avoid the need to use winecfg (which is annyoing in automation - you need to somehow close it), here is the full solution: create a `wine64`, then a `wine32` directory. If you use `winetricks` to check it (it gives a warning for `wine64` directories), it will report both correctly (`wine64` gives the warning, since it's 64, wine32 does not, since it's 32.). The solution;

```
rm -Rf ./wine   # carefull, this deletes your entire wine config (fine if you want to start afresh)

WINEPREFIX=~/.wine wineboot
```

...wait...

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 wineboot
```

After this, you can:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 your_32bit_executable.exe

WINEPREFIX=~/.wine WINEARCH=win64 your_64bit_executable.exe
```

Comment: It looks like on my Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 I did not need to delete the amd64 (win64) `./wine` folder. I had 3 programs previously installed and they kept working.
I did only create a specific win32 directory `./wine32`
Next I installed .NET 4.0 with the command 
`$ WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet40` and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue.

Type `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg`

It should start to download the drivers necessary. I believe this issue is due to a problem occurring during the normal download. For me it my internet dropped as it was originally downloading the drivers.

Comment: You do never need to run wine as root!

Answer (score 3):

Test if you already have multiarch enabled:

`dpkg --print-foreign-architectures | grep -q i386 && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Then install wine32:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine32`

And finally, don't delete your 64-bit wine install.  just rename it to .wine64 then create a new .wine folder for your 32-bit apps:

`mv ~/.wine ~/.wine64 && WINEARCH=win32 wineboot`

Answer (score 1):

After erasing .wine32, installing the .NET 4.0 with the command $ WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet40, worked for me.

kudos Antonio

Answer (score 1):

handy shell `.rc` snippet

```
alias wine32='WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.win32 wine'
alias wine64='WINEARCH=win64 WINEPREFIX=~/.win64 wine'
win32() {
    export WINEARCH=win32
    export WINEPREFIX=~/.win32
}
win64() {
    export WINEARCH=win64
    export WINEPREFIX=~/.win64
}
```