# How to install photoshop cs6?

Tags: graphics

I'd like to install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 12.10

I've tried searching software center but didn't find anything except gimp, but I want photoshop cs6 not anything else

Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the system requirements of Adobe Photoshop CS6? It won't be straightforward to install it on an operating system it's not designed for. And there are tons of similar how-to-install-Photoshop questions on this site. So... what have you tried?

Answer (score 10):

Here are your options.

1. [Use VirtualBox](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox) or something similar to actually create a virtual computer that you run Windows in.
2. Use Wine to run CreativeSuite. Wine is a way to run Windows software on Linux, but it's hit-or-miss.
3. Use [CrossOvier](http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=10329) to run CreativeSuite. CrossOver is based on Wine, but commercially supported. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they have much in the way of CS6, though earlier versions might be better supported.

Bottom line is, you can't directly run CS6 on Linux. VirtualBox will probably be the most reliable method, but that isn't really using Linux; it's using Windows, inside Linux.

Using wine, you get all the details / problems over [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607)

Answer (score 3):

You can install Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu using WINE1.5 or above.
I followed this guide and Im using Photoshop CS6 on my ubuntu 13.04

http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/2015/04/21/Install-Photoshop-CS6-on-Ubuntu.html

**extract from the above link:**

Enter the following commands into a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
#wine setup
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5

#change wine prefix
rm -rf .wine
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winecfg

#get winetricks script
wget http://kegel.com/wine/winetricks

#setup dependencies
sh winetricks -q atmlib gdiplus ie6 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 fontsmooth-rgb corefonts msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2010

#copy dll’s from windows
#Download DLL here : http://www.mediafire.com/?2zix528zkye5vky 


cp ~/odbc32.dll ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/
cp ~/odbcint.dll ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/


#photoshop setup
#You can download Photoshop CS6 here, link is mentioned on the website: http://www.ajinkyaxjs.com/2015/04/21/Install-Photoshop-CS6-on-Ubuntu.html


wine Setup.exe

#fontsmooth setup
winetricks fontsmooth-rgb

#run photoshop
wine '/home/ajinkya/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Photoshop.exe'
```

Comment: helped alot....  http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix this link helped to fix some bugs wile installation. now running cs6 on 14.04