# How can I install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: photoshop

How can I install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04? Anyone help me ?

Comment: Question and answer already exists here http://askubuntu.com/questions/244795/how-to-install-photoshop-cs6/348280#348280

Answer (score 36):

**Step 1. Install the Wine Team Ubuntu PPA**

First start by installing **Wine**. By the way, it's a utility to install windows apps in linux :

open the Terminal and :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa     
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

**Step 2. Using winetricks to get install dependencies for Photoshop CS6**

Now that we have the most recent build of wine, we can get started on fetching the necessary build packages to run the **Photoshop** installer.

Here’s the command to issue and pull those **dependencies**

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```

If a few errors pop-up, don’t worry – chances are this install will still work.

**Step 3. Running the Photoshop CS6 installer**

Now that you have all dependencies required to run Photoshop CS6, you can now run the Adobe setup. Either right click **Setup.exe**, or from the terminal:

```
cd /home/user/path/to/installer    
wine Set-up.exe
```

If everything worked as intended, you are now done. Photoshop should install like any other program via wine. It should even automatically appear in your programs list!

Comment: When install by command wine Photoshop_cs6.exe then show error 7-Zip: Data Error The archive is corrupted

Comment: check the executable file it's may be corrupted during the download process if you are using a download accelertor op try the folowing comman `sudo apt-get install p7zip{,-full}`

Comment: Showing me when run khan@raselkhan:~$ `winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko`
[sudo] password for khan: 
------------------------------------------------------
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
------------------------------------------------------

Comment: the step to pull dependencies give an error like the package does not work on 64bit installation

Comment: @Inquisitive 64bit is not yet stable, use the 32bit version

Comment: @RaselKhan You should run wine config at least once so it creates the user settings and folders (and env vars like %programfiles%, %windir% and such).
I think the answer should include that step too.

Comment: shows me `wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\user-setup.exe"` and `fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}`

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa     > !!! PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED !!!`

Answer (score 5):

[PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) supports [Adobe Photoshop cs6](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html).

Install PlayOnLinux like so:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After the POL installation has finished, click on `install` and, search for `Adobe Photoshop cs6`, click install, and follow the setup wizard.

From the [Adobe PhotoShop cs6 support page](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html):

> NOTE: This application does NOT work on Intel graphics (at least not
>   that I have seen). Nvidia and AMD graphics should be used.

Answer (score 3):

A more general answer:

Install [Virtualbox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/) from Ubuntu Software Center.

Alternatively visit the displayed "Developer Web Site" and get the very latest (look for Ubuntu *.deb files). *Please note that this requires a more manual installation method not described here - link https://www.virtualbox.org/.*

Note that "VirtualBox Extension Pack" is required for faster USB (2.0+) speeds.

With Virtualbox you will be able to install full versions of Windows versions
*(prior to "10" supported fully at this writing, VB 5.0.2)*.

This allows to create "Virtual machines", each running a "guest OS" on your Linux-based "host OS".

Most USB devices will be fully functional, others may depend on actual support from Virtualbox; expect Screen/Color calibrators, Image scanners, Barcode scanners, Printers and so on to be fully or partly functional - issues may exist with specific brands or models.

Network is supported in a few alternative modes, file shares can be crated, clipboard works in both directions host to guest and vice versa.

Depending on settings it may be possible to run software in a mode that makes it appear as if it were on the Linux OS (look for: Seamless windows).

*Recommended: Run Windows as a **network isolated** guest and skip the use of all antivirus and malware software - expect at least a 10% performance increase compared to a similar true machine due to this.*

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is only available for Windows platform

But on linux you can use Windows software through `wine`. So to use photoshop cs6 on ubuntu  first install wine using

```
 sudo apt-get install wine
```

Once it is installed, install photoshop using it.

Comment: See also: [Adobe Photoshop CS6 in the WineHQ App database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607).