# Installing Adobe Photoshop with Wine : OS requirement not met

Tags: wine, photoshop

I followed the steps in this post : [How can I install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Everything went fine until I got stuck on Step 3 because of a requirement issue in the installation process. The installation probably detects my OS is not a windows one and desactivates the Install button as shown in this picture.

[image]

Is there a way to circumvent this verification step? Any other advice to help succeed in installing Photoshop with wine? (I'd rather install with Wine than use a windows virtual machine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Wine, WinXP tends to be the current 'OS' to set up with on a default setup.  So, we need to tell Wine to emulate a Windows 7 environment instead of a Windows XP environment.

First, close the Photoshop installer completely.  Next, run `winecfg`.  In the "Applications" tab, where it says "Windows Version", select `Windows 7` from the drop down.

Restart the installer, and it *should* help fix it and it'll see Win7 instead of WinXP.