# Photoshop CS6 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: photoshop

I can't install Photoshop CS6 or any version. Any time I run it with Wine , when I need to upen it it gives me a : "Photoshop needs to run on a windows 7 machine" .. something like that. PLEASE HELP. I am a designer. I changed to Ubuntu for beautifulness, if I would've know I maybe shouldn't change to it. Please help. I have a macbook, if this help (I installed Ubuntu over my MacOS)

Comment: Photoshop CS6 is known not to run on wine. The only options are to dual boot or run in a VM such as KVM or virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question...

As answered by [zguell](https://askubuntu.com/users/251148/zguell) on a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04);

Step 1. Install the Wine Team Ubuntu PPA

First start by installing Wine btw it's a utility to install windows apps in linux :

open the Terminal and :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa     
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Step 2. Using winetricks to get install dependencies for Photoshop CS6

Now that we have the most recent build of wine, we can get started on fetching the necessary build packages to run the Photoshop installer.

Here’s the command to issue and pull those dependencies

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```

If a few errors pop-up, don’t worry – chances are this install will still work.

Step 3. Running the Photoshop CS6 installer

Now that you have all dependencies required to run Photoshop CS6, you can now run the Adobe setup. Either right click Setup.exe, or from the terminal:

```
cd /home/user/path/to/installer    
wine Set-up.exe
```

If everything worked as intended, you are now done. Photoshop should install like any other program via wine – It should even automatically appear in your programs list!

Also checkout Adobe photoshop cs6 on the [wine database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607)

Comment: I did that. No chance of working though. Also, If I try to run a virtual machine in Virtualbox I get a error about a driver not installed...

Comment: Have you tried running winecfg and changing the windows version to windows 7 as apposed to windows xp?

Comment: Can I at least run Photoshop CS4 or CS3? Any version is good..

Comment: Although that is the method to install photoshop, and although some people report it works, not all the features work and as you can see, most people report problems. Functionality is limited and in my experience, people wanting to run photoshop have a very low tolerance to the limited functionality.

Comment: please refer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)