# Help to UNINSTALL Photoshop. Please, help the Linux newbie)

Tags: uninstall, winetricks, photoshop

I am very fascinated with the professional help here on AskUbuntu. And I need your help again. I installed Ubuntu just two days ago and spent all this time setting it up. Now the question is about the Photoshop.

I followed this: https://askubuntu.com/a/530127/491656

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks

Everything was fine, but after the last one I got:

> winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko

I installed the Photoshop, but...I decided to delete all these and Photoshop, because I don't wont to use it in Linux. It feels like I miss Windows, but I don't. I'm looking forward to delete all files and dependencies installed so nothing left in Ubuntu. Could you please, help me to clarify what should I write in terminal?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before following CiberSheep instructions, you can delete Photoshop with the Wine Uninstaller. Run, in a terminal:

`wine uninstaller`

Find Photoshop and remove it.

After doing what CiberSheep said, run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove dependencies.

Comment: Easier to `rm -rf ~/.wine`

Comment: Okay. Thank you @Eduardo Cola for your response. So, I've done what you said, but it seems Photoshop uninstaller doesn't respond. It's frozen and doesn't respond...

Comment: Then find Photoshop's installation directory and remove it maually. If you installed it in Wine's "C:" drive run, in a terminal, `nautilus $HOME/.wine/drive_c` and look for it there.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen he might have installed Photoshop in a place other than Wine's C: drive. I always do it with my Windows games.

Comment: Okay, friends. So, I successfully uninstalled Photoshop and run <sudo apt-get purge wine>, but the answer is <Package 'wine' is not installed, so not removed>. What should I do?

Comment: First, I must tell you you didn't install the Wine version present in the official repository, you installed from third party PPA. Run `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.7` instead.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your patience! I I've done 'sudo apt-get remove --purge wine1.7' and 'sudo apt-get autoremove'. Thank you. But in the Menu I still have Winetricks. How whould I delete it?

Comment: By the way, buddy, I suggest you to understand the Linux command line a bit further before messing around with it. There are a few commands that can break your system down, and there are always graphical alternative ways of doing everything, remember that. I myself already broke many Linux installations until I learned.

Comment: Winetricks is not a Wine dependency, so it's not removed as Wine's orphan. Just run `sudo apt-get remove --purge winetricks; sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. We did it. And thank you for your suggestion to learn Linux before using command line. I really do  understand this and will follow your advice.

Comment: @EduardoCola - I would assume the OP installed to ~/.wine or if not s/he knows the name of the location.

Answer (score 0):

You can type this in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

That would be enough to uninstall and purge it. But it is important that you understand what you are doing ;) so at the beginning take some time to look for the commands you are going to type in the terminal.

You can take a look [here](http://www.unixguide.net/linux/linuxshortcuts.shtml).

Comment: I looked there. Thank you for that link. I'll learn how to manage that but I need some time. Btw, if I use <sudo apt-get purge wine> will it delete all dependencies?

Comment: That will NOT remove Photoshop.