# Newspaper graphic software

Tags: software-recommendation, web-design

Does Ubuntu have software like Windows has Photoshop and In-design (Qwark and page maker) that one can efficiently use to lay newspaper and magazine pages in a quick and easy to learn manner?

Answer (score 3):

With the right configuration [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) can replace Photoshop while [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net/) could replace In-design. You probably have to train a bit, but after that you should be able to use them.

You can both install through apt-get packet manager:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp scribus
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run both Adobe `Photoshop` and `Adobe Page Maker` in Ubuntu using `Wine`(A tool used to run windows apps under Linux),

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

you can find how to install Photoshop using Wine [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530110/how-can-i-install-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-14-04). 
To install Page Maker in Wine just run your `.exe` file.

Comment: Photoshop is working relatively well under wine. Don't expect perfection, though https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607

Comment: Much better :) +1