# Trying to switch to 32-bit Wineprefix from 64-bit Wine 1.6.2 (Trusty 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks

I'm having a little trouble with Wine 1.6.1. I recently downloaded some 32-bit games that I'd wanted to try (BeamNG Drive and Bugbear's Next Car Game demo) and I had run into some trouble trying to get either of these games to run. So I came across a couple pieces of advice on the 'Net, one here on the Ubuntu community site and the other at BeamNG's forums, on how to create a 32-bit wineprefix on a 64-bit setup.

I managed to be able to create the wine32 folder, but now I'm having trouble making it my default Wine setup. Anybody have any idea how I can do that?

I'll post the URLs for said advice, btw:

- http://www.beamng.com/threads/1788-Installing-DRIVE-under-Linux-via-Wine
- [How do I create a 32-bit WINE prefix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix)

Here's what I've tried so far in the Terminal:

```
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/user/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
wine: chdir to /home/user/wine32
 : No such file or directory
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/steven/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/steven/wine32'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ee890, overlapped 0x10ee89c): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/steven/wine32' has been updated.
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wine32 wine dxsetup.exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/steven/.wine32'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x103e2b8, overlapped 0x103e2d0): stub
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10fe890, overlapped 0x10fe89c): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/steven/.wine32' has been updated.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\dxsetup.exe"
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEARCH=win64 winecfgsteven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/steven/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/steven/.wine' is a 64-bit installation.
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/steven/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/user/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
wine: chdir to /home/user/wine32
 : No such file or directory
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX='/home/steven/wine32' WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX=/home/steven/wine32 WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot'
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ WINEPREFIX=/home/steven/wine32 WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
steven@steven-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$
```

I'm far from an expert and perhaps I've been going about it all the wrong way. In the meantime, I'll try to keep looking for solutions on my own.

Comment: I really, truly do need the help, folks. I haven't been able to find anything on Google that's been helpful in the least.

Answer (score 10):

Create a 32-bit Windows wine prefix:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
```

(or `win64` as winearch)

Usage of prefix - with env:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.wine32 command arguments[...]
```

command is like `wine setup.exe`.

For more info, see `man env`.

`$HOME/.wine32` is your prefix name (actually, `/home/username/.wine32`) and you have to specify it always to use it.

Default WINEPREFIX is ~/.wine, you can re-create it by removing (with any changes): **unrecommended**

```
rm -R ~/.wine
```

You cannot change architecture of a prefix without re-creation in future. For different games I recommend a separate wine prefix (or for different game clients like EA Origin)

Comment: I don't advise removing `~/.wine` - because Wine actually recommends keeping both prefixes - one for 64bit apps, and one for 32bit apps that won't run in the 64bit prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Just like you can't easily convert from a 32bit system to a 64bit system in place without a clean installation, you can't convert a 64-bit Wine prefix to a 32-bit one.  The only way to achieve this is to either blow away your wine prefix and replace it with a 32bit one, or create a separate 32-bit prefix.  Wine recommends the second of these options.

Wine even suggests that you keep separate prefixes if you need 32bit or 64bit.  The best guide for this is [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#32_bit_wineprefix) on Wine's wiki.  Effectively, run this command: `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/.wine32 winecfg` to create the `.wine32` folder/prefix.

From there, you can run the following: `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/$USER/.wine32 wine /path/to/exe`.  This will then run whatever `.exe` the path points to. You should use this entire command to effectively force run in the 32bit environment any 32bit programs that you need to run in that 32-bit prefix.

(NOTE: This information was partly obtained from the in-depth guide I wrote for the Secure Download Manager for Microsoft Dreamspark and such.  That is part of the notes [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31348).  Note that these steps here are extremely useful and are almost guaranteed to work as they are intended to.)