# Using Wine or Playonlinux

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I am new to ubuntu and I wanted to use wine or playonlinux to run games such as Fifa 07 or GTA san andears. I do have them as portable (preinstalled) games, I tried to run them but either they run but with weird resolutions or they don't run

is it possible to run them with wine and how? do I need installation CDs?

Thanks in advance 
Hasan

Answer (score 1):

You can find information on the support for various windows programms under http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps.html as well as https://appdb.winehq.org/.

Especially regarding the mentioned games:

- [Fifa 07](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=4277) ("Have tested it in Xubuntu (xfce) and works flawlessly")
- [GTA San Andreas](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iAppId=2599) ("Everything works and I mean everything.")

Comment: But do I need the installation CD? because as I mentioned I have them as portable files

Comment: By portable, you mean as *.iso-file or something else?

Comment: These are review of how well they work in Wine - they also give tips such as using a 32bit wine prefix [1](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6444&iTestingId=80559) (instructions on that are available [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix) (see also http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8d9263369d4c6d93a7cbacf2415377778c679d32). Then insert the CD and run the executable on the CD in terminal with `env WINEPREFIX="/home/USER/.WHATEVER/" wine /PATH/TO/FILE.EXE`.

Comment: Wineprefixes act like separate virtual windows drives (see [here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/dev-documentation-5.html) - note the instructions are more for PlayOnLinux) *@fret it would be a good idea to detail how to install wine and playonlinux*

Answer (score 0):

PlayOnLinux has never worked, so don't bother with that. It's malware.

By "portable preinstalled games" do you mean you copied the installation from elsewhere, or something like a repack?

Copying games like that rarely works, since you may not have the required system files installed that go along with them. You might go into Winecfg (in your terminal, just type winecfg and press enter) and in the libraries tab add the d3dx9 libraries. May as well add d3dx10, d3dcompiler, d3drm, dinput, dxgi, devenum, dbghelp, d3dxof (all libraries listed, there are several with different numbers). But my guess is that you'll need a reinstall, to get the required system files that came with the games.