# optirun playonlinux

Tags: graphics, playonlinux

If I use optirun to run playonlinux ( or **PRIMUS_SYNC=2 primusrun playonlinux** ) and then I choose a game that uses wine, does my game also use secondary graphic card ? I ask because I get low FPS as if I was using integrated graphic card. After launching the game I get following warning in Terminal: **primus: warning: recreating incompatible pbuffer**, can it cause any fps problems ? I have installed graphic driver and followed this tutorial [HOW TO PLAY LEAGUE OF LEGENDS ON UBUNTU 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459888/shop-and-in-game-item-shop-not-working-in-league-of-legend-lol/461256#461256) to install League of Legends but I still get much worse performance than on Windows7 (around 30 fps on Ubuntu, 60 fps on Windows) ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify the windows application directly when calling primusrun. You could try something like:

`primusrun wine "C:\path\to\your\windows\application.exe"`

Comment: When I try this way the game doesn't even start and I get such messages in terminal: _(  ERROR)[17:16:33.018] RADS::Common::RegistryHelp::RegKeyValueString::RegKeyValueString: Failed to find registry value "ProgramW6432Dir" (2).
charlie@charlie-K53SV:~/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends$ fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f914 1 C) semi-stub_ and some more similar errors.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue for LoL and wine. A quick Google search revealed this thread: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23105 and a potential solution. Can you try the solution they discuss and report back?

Comment: I wish I could try but I do not understand this : " So I fixed the problem, not sure what caused it, but I found out a workaround. I created a new directory with..
WINEPREFIX=/home/mafiajoe/kool WINEARCH=win32 wineboot
Installed to the folder
WINEPREFIX=/home/mafiajoe/kool wine [pathto .exe installer] " I do not know what commands I should type to achieve this.

Comment: In the solution mentioned in the post, the person first creates a new 32-bit wineprefix. In your case it probably should be something like 'WINEPREFIX="~/the_name_of_the_directory_for_the_prefix_goes_here" WINEARCH='win32' wine 'wineboot''
See also here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix
Then she installs LoL into the aforementioned prefix with 'WINEPREFIX=~/name_of_your_prefix wine /path/to/your.exe' 
Finally you need to start LoL with that prefix. Something like that should do it 'WINEPREFIX=/your_prefix wine /path/to/lol.launcher.exe'

Comment: And once that works you can try running LoL with primusrun. 'primusrun WINEPREFIX=/your_prefix wine "C:\path\to\your\windows\application.exe"'