# Wine not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, windows-8

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with Windows 8.1. I tried to run some applications with wine but it always shows the "Application has stopped working" error. As I had Windows 8 installed, I have Windows 8 selected in the wine menu. One game(EA Sports Cricket) started but as soon as the match starts, the game stops working.

What tweaks must be done to run the other applications?

Comment: Use the default Windows XP wineprefix, or if you need to the Windows 7 one (probably due to being developed for longer, the older versions can work better). If you are using 64bit ubuntu this might also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix

Comment: Also, EA Sports Cricket looks like it has a poor rating under Wine anyway https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18320&iTestingId=79170

Comment: Well, it's Platinum if you have updated graphics card drivers it seems... @Wilf

Comment: @Ads20000 It works fine on Windows 8. So, I guess I have updated graphic drivers.

Comment: @Yashbhatt you might have updated graphics drivers for Windows 8 (on Windows 8) but not for Linux (and on your Linux partition). Try my answer here to make sure you have the latest drivers Ubuntu recommends http://askubuntu.com/a/593767/125220 .

Comment: I see no drivers under additional drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's important to get familiar with their app database, [AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org), this has a lot of information on how well a program runs in Wine (because there's no guarantee it'll work well) and what tweaks you might need to make to get it to run well.

Secondly, if you find all that too complicated then you might want to try [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) which will usually apply all the necessary tweaks and install the best Wine version to (hopefully) get your program working.