# Can't install AMD Driver

Tags: drivers, ati

Hello guys for years I've been installing AMD drivers and usually no problems at all. I usuallu compile few .deb files with --buildpkg but today after installing latest Ubuntu 14.04 I got an error.

```
UBUNTU-MAIN:~$ sh omega.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty
Created directory fglrx-install.Jjz0kw
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-14.501.1003...................
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/trusty
Resolving build dependencies...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package (>
E: Unable to locate package 2
Unable to resolve  xserver-xorg-dev (>= 2.  Please manually install and try again.
^CSignal caught, cleaning up
xakep@UBUNTU-MAIN:~$
```

So okay no problem because of new installation even core xorg is not there so I decided to install them

```
UBUNTU-MAIN:~$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
xakep@UBUNTU-MAIN:~$
```

As you can see another set of errors. I mean whe way I see it it's a damn standard library that is not installing automatically as depended for some reason. Does anyone know why this is happening ? I mean this is a clean installation and I really havn't done anything diffirent this time around but I can;t install driver. Same error btw when installing steam, actual steam installed but on first boot you know how it installs all library it gave me exact error. some cheese-gtk23 and stuff can;'t be installed.

I am clueless on what is happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a better idea to install the drivers from Ubuntu's official 'Additional Drivers' utility rather than forcing AMD's packages to install (which might not always actually work in 14.04 as you've now found):

1. Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> (<kbd>Windows</kbd>) key, type in 'drivers' and click on 'Additional Drivers'.

[image]

2. Install the proprietary AMD driver that they recommend.

Comment: Understood, I'll try that.