# Photoshop in wine does not start - graphics driver problem?

Tags: software-installation, wine, photoshop

```
Executing wine vcredist_x86.exe
err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
fixme:clusapi:GetNodeClusterState ((null),0x32ebf4) stub!
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("y:\\9f0b7233c6f67752a0a0c705540f3ffd\\", 00000000): stub
err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f2d8,0x00000001,0x33f2c4) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
Executing w_do_call ie6
Executing load_ie6
------------------------------------------------------
This package does not work on a 64-bit installation
```

Comment: yes you literally deciphered it.  Should of elaborated, is Photoshop available in 32 bit package.  and will my graphic card even allow it @kos

Comment: If it was me and that was an option, I would try removing the nVidia drivers as suggested in the error message. I've never installed PhotoShop in WINE and rarely used WINE as well, so unfortunately that's all I have. If you want to give that a shot, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/206289/380067) for directions on how to uninstall the nVidia drivers / roll back to the Nouveau drivers.

Comment: `This package does not work on a 64-bit installation` — try [to create 32 bit prefix](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix). Don't forget to backup `~/.wine` directory before it *(if you already installed anything there)*.

Comment: Okay, as for the error about broken NVidia RandR — [here's the explanation](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/d575e0afe304d0096f8014f7f411bf28c126cc0b/dlls/winex11.drv/xrandr.c#L479). I won't leave it as an answer because I didn't manage to find what're those *DFP* and *DMT* to decypher the quote *(I didn't search hard though)*, so I'll leave it to anyone acknoweledged of what this is.

Answer (score 0):

1. What Photoshop version is it ?
2. As says  https://www.winehq.org/help : "If you want help with a single application our Application Database is a good place to look."   Example: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17