# Can Wine run windows 7 apps?

Tags: wine, windows-7

I'm playing Euro trucks and it needs windows 7. However, Wine hasn't windows 7 version and the game has many bugs. I can't play that game very well. how can I do it?

Comment: Here are the results for an Euro Trucks search in the Wine Database: https://www.winehq.org/search?q=euro+trucks

Comment: the game runs very well but after some days it has some bugs. for example delete my cargo and cancel my job.

Comment: Well that doesn't sound wine related to me (without having played it ever myself this sounds more like general game-bugs you would have on Windows as well)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Sometimes...

You can check the AppDB to see if your program is supported - for example, [Euro Truck Simulator](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7989) is rated Platinum (works great), while version 2 is rated [Gold](https://appdb.winehq.org//help/?sTopic=maintainer_ratings) (may need some fixes).

Also, in Wine Configuration it is possible to select which Windows version to act as:

[image]

But I think this does not make that much difference unless a program checks specifically for which Windows version it wants, or if it requires something only available on that version.

Wine [can implement DirectX](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Does_Wine_support_DirectX.3F_Should_I_install_Microsoft.27s_DirectX_under_Wine.3F) if needed (Version 9 works, 10+ have more limited support). If you don't have it you can use [Winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) to install it (look for `d3dx9` after running `winetricks dlls` - `d3dx9_??` describes certain [modules](https://wiki.winehq.org/DirectX-D3DX9) that may be needed). If you are using 64bit wine you will probably need to [create a 32bit wineprefix](https://askubuntu.com/a/177349/178596) first.

The game(s) require at least the following (source [[v1]](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/euro-truck-simulator) [[v2]](http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/euro-truck-simulator-2)):

- **CPU:**                Dual core CPU 2.4 GHz
- **RAM:**                4 GB RAM
- **GPU:**                GeForce GTS 450-class (Intel HD 4000)
- **DirectX:**            DirectX 9.0c
- **OS:**                 Windows 7
- **Storage:**            2.0 GB free hard disk space
- **ODD:**                DVD-ROM drive

Which I think your system with Wine can easily provide.

Comment: I saw the test results. the rate for Ubuntu 14.04 is platinum and you say this rate means the app hasn't any problem. but it has problems. I think the Tester didn't see the later bugs. is it true?

Comment: my system and wine version same as the tester, but it has some bugs. what is your mind? is possible the laptop isn't powerful or the game is crushed? because I use the illegal version of the game. and my wine version is 1.6.2. please tell me too, how I can add windows 7 and higher to the wine. thanks.

Comment: sorry forgot to add that particularly with games it can depend on the graphics drivers as to whether it works or not - but generally if you computer is above the system requirements (e.g. http://gamesystemrequirements.com/game/euro-truck-simulator ) you should be ok. What hardware and drivers (use `lspci -v`) are you using?

Comment: 6GB RAM and 2GB graphic card. CPU 2.3 GHz.

Comment: is DirectX needed?

Comment: yes but wine already has implementations of it.  By the way if you want you can add test data to the AppDB to describe how you installed it, which will help future users (or you can use it for future reference)

Comment: I've got multiple Win98/XP/7Vista applications that work fine or 98+% fine in Wine -- and I've attempted a couple that don't.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your Wine updated. CrossOver might also have some bug fixes (CrossOver is the paid version and usally get update before wine).

Wine also depends on how well your system is set up, Illegal versions of games might also be crippled, but gold editions are usually late version of games that also hold bug fixes.

I couldn't play Age of Mythology (Original paid version) before I changed to an (illegal I guess) gold version, but I had to fix 3D in the system (old Nvidia legacy laptop card had some hickups but is blazing fast now for what it is. Keywords: vdpau,vaapi and glx).

I still have some trouble with AoM using full screen Wine so the game must run windowed.

You can downgrade wine (if you update as I suggested) if trouble arises. Unlike Windows you still usually get the best from using the latest software, unless updates are in an alpha state.