# Unable to install Kindle using wine

Tags: wine, kindle

I attempted to install Kindle for PC on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with this command:

```
wine KindleForPc-installer-1.25.52064.exe
```

But I got this error:

[image: error screenshot]

I cannot make sense of it, being a casual user. 
Could anybody suggest a way to get out of this problem?

The terminal displays the text below as soon as the error box pops up.

```
[WARN][MazamaLog] QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with 
threads started with QThread
[ERROR][VersionInfo] Build version is not of the form 
major.minor.patch.revision
[INFO][CMetricsManager] Reporting the following metric 190202:132926 
Mazama: I Application:MZMA_OpenAfterFirstTimeInstall:
0030:err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code 80000003 flags 0 
addr 0x7bc7da14
```

Nothing happens once cancel is selected to debug.

Comment: @mikewhatever why do you say this is off topic? The OP is using Ubuntu.

Comment: Alok, did you try clicking on "Cancel" to start the debugger as the message suggests?

Comment: I did, but nothing really happened. The terminal stayed as it was.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the output you see after clicking on cancel? Or before? Please remember to be as specific as possible. The more details you give, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

you should use the command `winetricks`, and then choose:

> install an application

Kindle for PC is there, in an older version that works on Wine.

Answer (score 1):

To get newer versions running you need to apply the workaround mentioned here: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46320

In short you just need to create the following folder structure yourself:

```
users/<your username>/AppData/Local/Amazon/Kindle/crashdump
```

Afterwards the program shouldn't crash anymore on startup

EDIT:

Alternatively make sure you use a more modern version of Wine. When I tried Wine 7.22, this bug doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 32bit prefix and from then on it works fine. For how to do that, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177192/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-wine-prefix).